# Problem with putting Category "parent" and Subcategory ''child'' into a table

Tags: php, mysql, parent-child, categories

I tried to print an array of a parent child tree. The code I used does not seem to print anything.

```
<?php
$sql = "

SELECT *,
       category_name parent_category_name,
       '' path
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN categories ON parent_id = id
ORDER BY parent_id, id

";

function print_row ( $rowdata )
{
?>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <?=$rowdata['id']?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <?=$rowdata['path']?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <?=$rowdata['type']?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <?=$rowdata['status']?>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
<?php

}

$stmt  = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$printed = array();

foreach ($data as $row)
{

   if ( $row['parent_id'] == '' )
   {
      $row['path'] = $row['category_name'] . '/';
      $printed[$row['id']] = $row;
   }
   else
   {
      $row['path'] = $printed[$row['parent_id']]['path'] . $row['category_name'] . '/';
      $printed[$row['id']] = $row;
   }
}


array_multisort(array_column($printed, 'path'), SORT_ASC, $printed);

foreach ( $printed as $prow )
{
   print_row ( $prow );
}
?>
</table>
```

Mysql Categories

| id | parent_id | category_name | category_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | General | desc |
| 2 | 1 | Announcements | desc |

The result that I want to create looks like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/01FTe.png]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem because the `<?php ?>` also causes other parts of HTML to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Before even testing it, the query you put there looks very strange to me. But I try to test it anyway. And after testing it, your query crash with an error.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INT,
  category_name VARCHAR(256),
  category_description VARCHAR(256),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO categories(category_name, category_description) VALUES 
     ('General', 'desc'),
     ('Announcements', 'desc');
     
UPDATE categories SET parent_id = 0 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE categories SET parent_id = 1 WHERE id = 2;
```

I use this script to build the table, and when doing the query you put in your questions, it will crash with this error: `Not unique table/alias: 'categories'`. Here's the fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b5d95/22

Now this error simply means, you have 2 table using the same name/alias, which is categories and itself. Then I think what you actually want from the query is something like this

```
SELECT 
  child.id AS id,
  child.category_name AS category_name,
  child.category_description AS category_description,
  child.parent_id AS parent_id,
  parent.category_name AS parent_category_name
FROM 
  categories AS child
  LEFT JOIN categories AS parent 
    ON parent.id = child.parent_id
ORDER BY parent.parent_id, child.id
```

Notice how I put an alias of "child" and "parent" to the table? This is needed so MySql can know which table you're referring to, and so that it will not be treated as "duplicated".

Now, I don't see a reason to doing `SELECT '' AS path` you can just initialize them directly in the PHP. Using `*` and then adding `category_name parent_category_name` doesn't really make sense either, the `*` already select for everything in the joined tables, and the result will also contains some unused or redundant columns, so I think you better off just select what you need.

My query result:

| id | category_name | category_description | parent_id | parent_category_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | General | desc | 0 | (null) |
| 2 | Announcements | desc | 1 | General |

After all of that, I assume the actual query you're using might be different? And the one you posted is just a bad copy paste or something, but if it is what you're using, that's the problem.

Edit: And actually after your comments, you can just use a regular select to do this

```
SELECT * FROM categories
```

And it will also work just fine

Edit: I have tested your PHP part of code, and it is working properly for the most part, except for these 2

```
// Maybe instead of these 2
<?=$rowdata['type']?>
<?=$rowdata['status']?>
// You want this:
<?=$rowdata['category_name']?>
<?=$rowdata['category_description']?>
```

The data doesn't contains "type" and "status" column, so I'm not sure what do you want here. Other than that, you need to put wrap the print_row loop into a proper table, something like this:

```
...
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Path</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Desc</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    foreach ( $printed as $prow )
    {
        print_row ( $prow );
    }
?>
</table>
...
```

And then after modifying that 2 and plug it into an HTML, I got something like this:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Path</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Desc</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>General/</td>
        <td>General</td>
        <td>desc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>General/Announcements/</td>
        <td>Announcements</td>
        <td>desc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: there is no need for a parent_category_name because the parent_id should be able to retrieve the parent category.

Comment: yeah you can also do that, but that means you don't even need the join, just use the raw row result without any join and you're good. Anyway so what's the status of your question then? Do you still have issue after you fix the query?

Comment: I still cant find a way to print the categories and subcategories in a loop

Comment: @Babo See my edits for something you might need to fix. Honestly, after going back and forth, I think your question wasn't clear enough. At first, I thought it was because you don't understand what's the problem. But clearly you do have some understanding. And now I see that your code has a `</table>` at the end. But I don't see the top part so maybe that's the problem?
Anyway if it isn't your problem, you may need to give me a better explanation of the situation, because your code at least to some extend, **doesn't** have any problem (I have tested this too)

Answer (score -1):

first, you can get your parents data with zero parent_id:

```
$parentsData = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from categories where parent_id=0")->execute()->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

and in foreach parentsData, send query again with parent id:

```
foreach($parentsData as $parentRow){
  echo 'parent title: '.$parentRow['category_name'].'<br>child list: ';
  $childs = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from categories where parent_id=".$parentRow['id'])->execute()->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  foreach($childs as $child){
    echo 'parent title: '.$child['category_name'];
  }
}
```